# are the rational numbers (with initial topology) locally connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If you set the initial topology on $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \rightarrow x$ . Is it locally connected or not? and why ?

Comment: What are the connected sets in $Q$. Can a connected set have more than one element?

Answer (score 5):

In fact, $\Bbb Q$ is [totally disconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space) in this topology (meaning connected subsets have at most one point), but no singleton in $\Bbb Q$ is the preimage of an open set (why not?). Hence, *no* point of $\Bbb Q$ has a connected open neighborhood *at all*, so it cannot be locally connected.

As for how to see that $\Bbb Q$ is totally disconnected in this topology, we may use the following facts:

- The continuous image of a connected set is connected.
- The map $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$ given by $x\mapsto x$ is continuous by definition.
- The connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are the empty set, singletons, intervals (open, closed, half-open), rays (open or closed), and $\Bbb R$ itself. Which of these are images of subsets of $\Bbb Q$ under the map $x\mapsto x$? Hence, which subsets of $\Bbb Q$ can be connected?

Comment: Better yet, it’s $0$-dimensional!

Answer (score 3):

Another way, perhaps less pedantic, to say "initial topology" could be "subspace topology"?   :-)

Anyway, a topological space $X$ is locally connected at $x\in X$ if for every open neighbourhood $U \subset X$ of $x$ there is a connected open set $V \subset X$ such that $x \in V \subset U$.

So you are lead to study connected open sets in $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, right?

Which, by definition, are intersections of open sets $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$: $U \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

You can assume that your open set $U$ is just an interval $(a,b)$, since these form a basis of $\mathbb{R}$. That is we can focus ourselves in sets like $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Now the question is: how many connected intersections of this kind do you know?